# Passing Selected option from dropdown in the url Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have two problems 1) the first is i can't add a param from dropdown selected option To address URL. i have already a param from previous page that i send country , i have. dropdown cities for each country My url : www.example.com/countries/?country=Us

My dropdown display data in html table for each city
My dropdown code : 
countries.php (template)

```
    <span>Cities </span>
    <select name="state" id="address" class="form-control aqarey-control" 
    onchange="citySelectedFunction()">
    <?php
    Global $wpdb;
    $code = get_query_var('country');
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT city, latitude, longitude, zonetime 
    FROM location WHERE country = '$code'");
    foreach($result as $row) {
    $long=$row->longitude;
    $lat=$row->latitude;
    $zone=$row->zonetime;
    $city=$row->city;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $city . '#' . $long . '#' . $lat . '#'. $zone; ? 
    >"><?php echo $city ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>






function citySelectedFunction() {
    var data = document.getElementById("address").value.split("#");
    var city = data[0];
    var long = data[1];
    var lat = data[2];
    var zone = data[3];

    var B = document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML =  lat;
    var C = document.getElementById("long").innerHTML =  long;
    var D = document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML = zone;
    var E = document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city;
    var test2 = B;
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = test2;

    var test1 = C;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = test1;

    var testtt = D;
    document.getElementById("timezone").value = testtt;



window.location.href = `http://localhost:8888/horaire/pays/?country=${city}`;

}
```

the result of `window.location.href =`http://exemple.com/pays/?country=${city}`;` and empty dropdown

output => http://exemple.com/pays/?country=Elbasan Without the param of country $code

function.php

```
add_action('init','wpse46108_register_param');
function wpse46108_register_param() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('country'); 
}
```

I want to add text of selection options to url like : www.example.com/countries/Us/newyork

(countries is a template page and is page for each country) , if i got to www.example.com/Us/newyork      It would be very cool

how i can do that with wordpress , I try a lot of solutions and it didn't work

My goals : 
- Add selected option from dropdown to URL
- URL

Please can anyone help me!